# How to instantiate object in UserControl.Resources?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-2.0

I am designing a listbox and I want to have design time data
in it.

If have a class in my namespace, how do I instantiate
and object of that class in the Resources of the user control
XAML please?

Malcolm

Answer (score 3):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <my:CustomObject xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" 
                     x:Key="MyCustomObj"
                     Property="Value"
    />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: What is the point of xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" ?  Do you need this if the "my" namespace is defined in the top-level <UserControl> element?

Comment: So why, when I do this, do I get an error that the designer cannot find the MyCustomObj class?  It should be able to.  (I am debugging the designer as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514636.aspx )